# ES2015 import of jQuery not working in test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use ES2015 modules on a new project, and get that working with unit testing with Mocha and Chai via gulp. I'm importing jQuery into the source module (so that it can call `getJSON()`), but while the main `$` function seems to be present, the functions attached to it - like `getJSON` or `attr` - are not.

Here's a minimal test case:

```js
// minimal-test-case.js
import $ from "jquery";

export function minimalTestCase1() {
  return $;
}

export function minimalTestCase2() {
  return $.getJSON;
}
```

And here's the corresponding test for it:

```js
// minimal-test-case-test.js
import {expect} from "chai";
import {describe, it} from "mocha";
import {minimalTestCase1, minimalTestCase2} from "../../../app/es/services/minimal-test-case.js";

describe("a minimal test case", () => {
  it( "should be able see jquery", () => {
    expect(minimalTestCase1()).to.be.a.function;
  } );

  it( "should be able see jquery functions", () => {
    expect(minimalTestCase2()).to.not.be.undefined;
  } );
});
```

Test case 1 succeeds, but test case 2 fails.

The corresponding gulp task is:

```js
function testUnitTask() {
  return gulp
    .src(["test/unit/**/*.js"])
    .pipe(gulpMocha({
      compilers:babelCompiler
    }));
}
gulp.task("test:unit", testUnitTask);
```

The `import` pattern seems to be one that I've seen used elsewhere. Why can't I see `$.getJSON`?

Comment: Sounds like you have a conflict. Does the `jQuery` object work any better than `$`?

Comment: I'm afraid that `jQuery` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you're getting the dummy function jQuery exports when it detects that it is in a commonjs environment and when no global document is available. I advise adding jsdom to your test setup and adding a minimal setup file like this

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
global.document = jsdom('<body></body>');
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.navigator = window.navigator;
global.XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to import jquery in your tests if that is your kind of thing.

```
Something like this
import $ from 'jquery';
describe('Prepop test Page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        $('head').append('<meta name="api_token" content="some token" />');
        $('head').append(`<meta name="sample_data" content="${sampleData}"/>`);
        $('head').append('<meta name="action_url" content="/api/ext/v1/prepop/" />');
        $('body').append('<div> </div>');
```

You then mock your jquery functions and selectors whenever possible.